# Quarkus - Use Postman to query resources which are secured by TLS/SSL

Tags: certificate, postman, quarkus

I followed the following example https://quarkus.io/blog/quarkus-mutual-tls/

In this example two quarkus applications are created, a "server" and a "client". Additionally two java keystores are created, each for one of them.

On the server the server.keystore is used to enable SSL. The resources are reachable via https on the set port.

Now I want to use postman to query these resources. I know that I can add client certificates to postman.  For that I need an crt and key file or an pfx file, which is a container like java keystores if I am right. I used keystore explorer (gui tool) to export crt and key file from the server.keystore and added it as client certificate on postman.

But every request I do with postman fails with "Error: error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT".

Any help or advice?

Comment: when ypu disable ssl from postman settings are you able make it work?

Comment: yes, if i disable ssl check in postman it works. But I don't want to disable them. I want to setup postman correctly.

Comment: you should be adding ca and not client certificate as you are just trying to get a resource from a server

Comment: But I want to use a client certificate to authorize the client to the server. The server should acknowledge me like it's done in the linked blog post.